# Showing date of alarm in top tray

Tags: 7.0-nougat, alarm

On my Zenfone AR with Android 7.0, I am annoyed that the alarm notifications show the time of the next alarm, but not the day. In the example below, I have an alarm set for 06:00 two days from now, but looking at this screen, it looks to me as if the alarm would be set for tomorrow morning. There's no way to check what day I will be woken up early other than going into the alarm app and checking my list of alarms there.

Is there any way to change this? (The same thing goes for the lock screen.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: using the [Shortcutter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leedroid.shortcutter) app for custom QuickSetting tiles, it's possible to add a "next alarm" icon (and several other tweaks too).

[image]